# Handle arrays/hashes from table text columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying to manage user permissions in the following way:

In my database I have created a table with a column called 'permission_posts'. The data in the 'permission_posts' is text and an example of its content is as follows:

```
write = false
read = true
...
```

I would like to access the value of 'write' and 'read' to manage the user actions.
In my case, what can I do to easly retrieve true/false values of write/read attributes?

Being new to RoR, I went to search around the internet and I found something that may not need to reach my goal: to serialize data and to convert a string to an array and then search in it. For both of these alternatives (if they are valid) I do not know how to proceed.

P.S.: is it a safe method to manage user permissions? is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should separate the text column in at least two, so that the table looks like:

```
(user_id, action, is_permitted)
```

or, even,

```
(user_id, action_id, is_permitted)
```

Another possible approach you can take, but only if the set of actions is fixed:

```
(user_id, action1_permitted, action2_permitted ...)
```

Comment: I think I'm going to use the third option that you suggested me: (user_id, action1_permitted, action2_permitted ...).

The only doubt is that I can have a table with many columns, each for every action related to every object! This is why I wanted to handle the actions as described in the original Question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this is a good way, but I think it worth here for reference.

I would store the permission as an integer instead of a string. The value depends on the write and read values. So the write is the first bit and the read is the second bit (represented by a integer in binary, because they are true and false only)

So

```
write = false, read = false => 00 => 0
write = true,  read = false => 01 => 1 (although this one seems strange :D)
write = false, read = true  => 10 => 2
write = true,  read = true  => 11 => 3
```

So if you want to search the users who have read permission but have no write permission, you just search by the value `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using migrations? The normal Rails procedure would be to generate a model:

```
script/generate model Permission user_id:integer action:string is_permitted:boolean
```

then migrate the database to create the table. Then associate the table to the user (User has_many Permissions).

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach and use something that's already there based on what I need:

- Basic user permissions: [Nifty
  authentication](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators)
- More advanced granularity needs: [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) -- [training here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)
- Complete and modular solution: [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) -- [training here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

Another approach if you want a one to many user - permissions would be to use a bitmask.
[Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association) an example with roles which can be adapted to your needs.